# Issue in setting up RT5’s database

Tags: linux, perl, rt

I am following [this](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/ManualInstallation) tutorial
to set up RT5 in a virtual machine with ubuntu 18.
Currently I am in the setting up RT's database step but when I try to run the code `sudo /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-setup-fulltext-index --noask --dba=rt_admin`
to set up full-text indexing I get the following errors.

```
WWW::Form::UrlEncoded::XS 0.26 is required. fallback to PP version at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1/WWW/Form/UrlEncoded.pm line 17.
Can't locate RT/Extension/MandatorySubject.pm in @INC (you may need to install the RT::Extension::MandatorySubject module) (@INC contains: /opt/rt5/sbin/../local/lib /opt/rt5/local/plugins/RT-Extension-MergeUsers/lib /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT.pm line 790.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-setup-fulltext-index line 75.
```

The problem is that for example `WWW::Form::UrlEncoded::XS` 0.26 version cannot be installed in ubuntu 18 and for other dependencies, it is suggested to install, even after installing, it keeps on bringing some new dependencies which actually are already installed.

Any heads up on this issue will be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The [installation tutorial](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/ManualInstallation) uses [`App::Virtualenv`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Virtualenv) to create an isolated Perl environment. Did you use that module?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this message:

```
Can't locate RT/Extension/MandatorySubject.pm in @INC
```

suggests that you are loading some extensions that may not be installed yet. To get through the initial installation process, you can comment out any "Plugin" lines in your `RT_SiteConfig.pm` file. Then once you have the base install running, you can find updated versions of modules and install them.

`WWW::Form::UrlEncoded::XS` isn't a core dependency of RT, so my guess is that could be getting required by another extension.

Comment: Addressing provided solutions. Yes, I have used the Virtualenv module. Using fixdeps and makedeps I do not get any issues and I have also added Set(@Plugins,qw(RT::Extension::MandatorySubject) ); in the rt_steconfig and tried to follow the documentation by Mandatorysubject but it does not work. Following is the error after I run "perl Makefile.PL" inside the RT-Extension-MandatorySubject-0.05 DIRECTORY. Unknown function is found at Makefile.PL line 3. Execution of Makefile.PL aborted due to runtime errors. This is line 3 of makefile.pl=> RTx('RT-Extension-MandatorySubject');